# Disable EF Core "QuerySplittingBehavior.SingleQuery" warning

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, nlog

I use a lot of multiple `Include` on EF entities in my aspnet core project.
I now have prod log littered with those:

```
13:49:54.0149751|Warn|Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query|Compiling a
  query which loads related collections for more than one collection
  navigation either via 'Include' or through projection but no 
  'QuerySplittingBehavior' has been configured. By default Entity 
  Framework will use 'QuerySplittingBehavior.SingleQuery' which can 
  potentially result in slow query performance. See 
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2134277 for more information. 
  To identify the query that's triggering this warning call 
  'ConfigureWarnings(w => 
    w.Throw(RelationalEventId.MultipleCollectionIncludeWarning))'
```

I would like to disable either the warning all together or filter it before it gets logged.

I use `nlog.web` and the logging is configured in `appSettings.json`

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "Warning",
      "IdentityServer4": "Information"
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable the warning for that message by configuring your DbContext. In the `OnConfiguring` method, add this line:

```
optionsBuilder
    .ConfigureWarnings(x => x.Ignore(RelationalEventId.MultipleCollectionIncludeWarning));
```

However, I would suggest that fixing the queries that are causing this in the first place - these warnings exist for a good reason.

Comment: Hey, this is inside the warning message (at the end). Just they suggest `Throw` to identify the query and fix it.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yup, that's why I suggested that OP fixes it rather than hide it.

Comment: No thank you. I do not want to "fix" them. But thanks for the tip. Any way to configure it in json?

Comment: I was tempted to say you could add `"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query": "None"` to your logging config, but that would turn all warnings off. Maybe `Error` would be a better level.

Comment: nw I separated it to a new question. thanks